# MySQL balance calculation - separate table or query to calculate everytime?

Tags: mysql, triggers, transactions

I have a few tables with a money transfer application. Different tables will contain money-in and money-out data for customers. I need to calculate their overall balance and have two options:

1. Have a separate table to show customers' last balance and use triggers to update the balance field whenever some changes occur in other related tables
2. Calculate customers' balance from scratch every time they inquire their balance. This involves going through a few tables and calculating every transaction, every time.

Which one is more efficient?

The only disadvantage of the first one is that I might need 3 (insert, update, delete) triggers for all the related tables.

Comment: How frequent are balance inquiries compared to transactions?

Comment: transactions are much more frequent than balance inquiries. But I can't give a ratio, even a rough one.

Comment: Not even if it's 1:10 or more like 1:1000000?

Comment: 1:10 is more like it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separte table with your customer's balance, you can use data to bring adittional information to your users such as reports, stats, etc...

It needs a bit more job but maybe in the future you find this separate info useful for this.